# displaying Simple XML php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am looking for something equivalent to this:

```
$e= xmlwriter_open_uri("test.xml");
....
print htmlentities(xmlwriter_output_memory($e));
```

now this print allows to display whats in the xml list into a table.

But my with my simple xml (combined with $dom for formatting) i have no idea how to display this. Although this generates the proper output i wish into the xml how do i display the xml below? Something similar to a print or?

The purpose is to display the values of the xml into a table.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<test></test>');       
    $one= $xml->addChild('enemy', 'yes');           
    $two= $xml->addChild('friend', 'maybe');           

$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->save('test.xml');
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stringify (*technical term!*) the `SimpleXMLElement` to load it into a `DOMDocument`, in fact that's a terrible idea (though, you're forgiven).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<test></test>');
$one= $xml->addChild('enemy', 'yes');
$two= $xml->addChild('friend', 'maybe');

// Get the DOMDocument associated with this XML
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

echo $dom->saveXML(); // or echo htmlentities($dom->saveXML()) if you really must
```

More info about retrieving a `DOMElement` (and its `DOMDocument`) from a `SimpleXMLElement` can be found in the docs for [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml).